# does power map work with a specific type of data set?

Tags: excel, dictionary, business-intelligence, powerpivot

Sometimes when I want to use my data sets on the Power Map, it doesn't work. It recently gave me an error that this operation is not possible with the 32 bit office version and most of the time it doesn't show anything on the map. Could you please advise me if I need to have a specific data set in my excel sheet?

Also in order to use this data on Power Map, does it has to be in the PowerPivot work book or it can work regardless?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't need to be in PowerPivot You need some Geo field in your data. just highlight a cell or the whole table and click Power Map. A lot of the tips is in the help.
If you have a lot of data, you need the 64 bit version of Office.
Finally, it is always good to make sure you have the latest driver for your graphics card (from the manufacture), Power Map is a heavy graphics application and it exposes some bugs in drivers (that is normally fixed in newer versions)

Comment: Yes, it seems like I need to upgrade my office from 32 to 64 bit as the data set i was using was huge..many thanks for your help!